# How can we add button to toggle css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add button to toggle the animation for this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kumargaurav845/bjwhm3bf/). I have added the following code but I'm not able to toggle (start and stop) the animation.

```css
body .a [class^="b"] {
  width: 200px;
  height: 142.8571428571px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 71.4285714286px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  border-radius: 100% 300%;
  background: radial-gradient(bottom left, transparent 41.4285714286px, #ff0c0c 41.4285714286px, #3f0000 -15px, #ff0c0c 71.4285714286px);
  /*  -webkit-box-shadow: 71.4285714286px 71.4285714286px 142.8571428571px darkred;*/
  box-shadow: 71.4285714286px 71.4285714286px 142.8571428571px rgb(164, 69, 14);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Comment: What button? Your fiddle doesn't seem configured correctly either; you've put HTML in the JS section.

Comment: I want to add button to start/stop the animation

Answer (score 0):

demo is here: https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/bjwhm3bf/3/

first,i remove this code to html,and change it's value to stop

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="stop"></input>
```

second,i give the button css:

```
body #button {
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

third,i add this javascript :

```
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var animationPlayStateEle = document.querySelectorAll('.a [class^="b"]');

  if (this.value === 'start') {
      Array.from(animationPlayStateEle, function(ele) {
          ele.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
      });
      this.value = 'stop';
  } else if (this.value === 'stop') {
      Array.from(animationPlayStateEle, function(ele) {
          ele.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
      });
      this.value = 'start';
  }

}, false);
```

then ,job finished;
the core is that,when you click the button and the button's value==='stop',i change this

```
    .a [class^="b"] {
        animation-play-state: play;
    }
```

to

```
    .a [class^="b"] {
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
```

in the javascript by change the element's style;
and when you click the button and the button's value==='start',i change this

```
    .a [class^="b"] {
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
```

to

```
    .a [class^="b"] {
        animation-play-state: running;
    }
```

clear?

Comment: Thanks a lot lu xiansheng, I got my requirement